# A contest for UK-based Android.SE users (Updated)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Droidcon UK is hosting a [**contest**](http://uk.droidcon.com/content/small-challenge-you-week).

Live in the UK and rack up big points at Android.SE this week and you could win a [Sony Ericsson Xperia Play](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/mobilephones/overview/xperia-play-4g?cc=us&lc=en).

Check the [contest site](http://uk.droidcon.com/content/small-challenge-you-week) for details. A winner will be announced October 7.

**Edit:** UK Contestants: Please make sure you have specified your location in your Stack Exchange profile.

Thanks!